# failed to build image on macos M1: gcc: error: missing argument to ‘-march=’

Tags: macos, docker, apple-m1

when building image on macos with M1, i got an error below:

```
    Collecting python-Levenshtein==0.12.2
  Using cached python-Levenshtein-0.12.2.tar.gz (50 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-Levenshtein==0.12.2) (33.1.1)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for python-Levenshtein, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: python-Levenshtein
    Running setup.py install for python-Levenshtein ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z9yhh5ds/python-levenshtein_e99c5f8b2a70415d998d3534a8b15e14/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z9yhh5ds/python-levenshtein_e99c5f8b2a70415d998d3534a8b15e14/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-60fgubma/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.6m/python-Levenshtein
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-z9yhh5ds/python-levenshtein_e99c5f8b2a70415d998d3534a8b15e14/
    Complete output (31 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/Levenshtein
    copying Levenshtein/StringMatcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/Levenshtein
    copying Levenshtein/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/Levenshtein
    running egg_info
    writing python_Levenshtein.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to python_Levenshtein.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to python_Levenshtein.egg-info/entry_points.txt
    writing namespace_packages to python_Levenshtein.egg-info/namespace_packages.txt
    writing requirements to python_Levenshtein.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to python_Levenshtein.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'python_Levenshtein.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.project' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.pydevproject' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'python_Levenshtein.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/Levenshtein
    copying Levenshtein/_levenshtein.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/Levenshtein
    running build_ext
    building 'Levenshtein._levenshtein' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/Levenshtein
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/Levenshtein/_levenshtein.o
    gcc: error: missing argument to ‘-march=’
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z9yhh5ds/python-levenshtein_e99c5f8b2a70415d998d3534a8b15e14/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z9yhh5ds/python-levenshtein_e99c5f8b2a70415d998d3534a8b15e14/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-60fgubma/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.6m/python-Levenshtein Check the logs for full command output.
```

My Dockerfile is :

```
FROM ***:21.06.22.1038
# install related packages
COPY target/requirements.txt /root/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /root/requirements.txt -i https://pypi.douban.com/simple/
```

And my requirements.txt is:

```
pymysql
requests==2.21.0
xlrd==1.2.0
tornado==5.1.1
pypinyin==0.35.3
python-Levenshtein==0.12.2
thrift==0.13.0
jieba==0.42.1
Cython==0.28.5
elasticsearch==7.13.1
scikit-learn==0.18.2
ConcurrentLogHandler==0.9.1
tormysql==0.4.2
truepy==2.0.4
redis==3.0.1
redis-py-cluster==2.0.0
```

The version of my base image is python3.6.8, and if i delete python-Levenshtein==0.12.2 from requirements.txt, it will success.

i`ve already installed:

```
wget aclocal automake autoconf make gcc gcc-c++ python3-devel mysql-devel bzip2 libffi-devel openssl-devel epel-release python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-libs
```

in my base image.

Comment: Please edit your question to include specifics about what you were doing. Currently you've only included some error output (I fixed the formatting, as it was originally unreadable). It's unclear what, exactly, is happening, without more specific details.